# How to get credentials file used in HFC SDK for chain-code development environment?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing my chain code application in development environment provided by hyperledger fabric. I want to have an web UI for this application. IBM-BlockChain has provided an example of using HFC SDK with node.js app. I am trying to follow the same example as shown here [SDK-Demo](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/SDK-Demo). This example is deployed on IBM-BlueMix and has ServiceCredentials.json file which contains entries like

```
{
"peers": [
{
  "discovery_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp3.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "discovery_port": 30001,
  "api_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp3.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "api_port_tls": 5001,
  "api_port": 5001,
  "event_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp3.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "event_port": 31001,
  "type": "peer",
  "network_id": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271",
  "container_id": "b90e4977ff987e34ceb193daafdf7723751f6a195771125a12051ac44442367e",
  "id": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp3",
  "api_url": "http://36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp3.us.blockchain.ibm.com:5001"
},
{
  "discovery_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "discovery_port": 30001,
  "api_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "api_port_tls": 5001,
  "api_port": 5001,
  "event_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "event_port": 31001,
  "type": "peer",
  "network_id": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271",
  "container_id": "dea7d34e49827e1ddb465fae16bb40724a7aeaac8775d8193a7071f0cf51e13b",
  "id": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp0",
  "api_url": "http://36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com:5001"
},
],
"ca": {
  "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-ca": {
  "url": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-ca.us.blockchain.ibm.com:30001",
  "discovery_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-ca.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "discovery_port": 30001,
  "api_host": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271-ca.us.blockchain.ibm.com",
  "api_port_tls": 30001,
  "api_port": 30001,
  "type": "ca",
  "network_id": "36a78535bcdf4ef0g96h85619i046271",
  "container_id":   "0083cc6af273d82a18698763348494708063af871bead073f1899ce1726f5e07"
}
},
"users": [
  {
  "enrollId": "admin",
  "enrollSecret": "c62d4d9a5d",
  "affiliation": "group1",
  "username": "admin",
  "secret": "c62d4d9a5d"
  },
  {
  "enrollId": "WebAppAdmin",
  "enrollSecret": "50dd43e4c0",
  "affiliation": "group1",
  "username": "WebAppAdmin",
  "secret": "50dd43e4c0"
  }
],
"cert": "https://blockchain-certs.mybluemix.net/us.blockchain.ibm.com.cert",
"cert_path": "/certs/peer/cert.pem"
}
```

I am not using IBM-BlueMix so can't get the auto-generated credentials file. 
How do i generate credentials file for my environment?

Comment: Did u figure it out? U should open an issue on sdk-demo repo